# CSS3 to only style if a child is hidden

Tags: css

Given the html below, using just CSS, no JS/jQuery - How can I style the first LI > A in a specific way only if the second LI (.dropdown-optional) is hidden (display:none).

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="btn">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown-optional">
    <a class="btn">Item 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible using just CSS. You will need JS.

Comment: If you would add a css class to the dropdown-optional instead of setting the display:none, you could use the css3 general sibling selector: li.hidden~li { /* css */ } http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators It's a bit buggy in IE though..

Comment: Johan, you can't do it that way, not in this case at least. Unfortunately the sibling selector works only if the selector declared after the `~` comes after the one declared before it in the html(not the best phrasing, I agree). For instance, `p ~ a` only works on `a` elements which are preceded ('not necessarily immediately') by a `p` element

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo i was not aware of this, thanks for correcting me ^^

Comment: I'd approach it with a slightly different twist. By applying a class (.optional-dropdown-show) to the parent UL, you can then use CSS to hide .dropdown-optional, e.g: .dropdown-optional { display:none; }, .optional-dropdown-show .dropdown-optional { display:block; }. From here, you can then style the first anchor link, conditional on the UL class (e.g: ul > li > a.btn { color:red; }, along with ul.optional-dropdown-show > li > a.btn { color:green; }. Of course, depending on your exact scenario or other needs, this might not work for you.